# Cannot trash old shared PC

Tags: trash, macos

There is an old shared connection that I had setup to a PC to transfer files from the PC to the Mac and I cannot get rid of it.

[image: Here is a shot of the old connection I'm trying to trash.]

Here is a shot of the message when I drag to the trash; control click give no trash option.

[image: Shot of file with delete message]

Comment: why not? what does it say/do? did you disable it in Sharing?

Comment: In other words, what did you try?  And then, why didn't it work?

Comment: Is the PC still connected to your network?

Comment: No, PC hasn't been connected for at least a year.

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling / re-enabling Bonjour:

[image: Finder --> Preferences]

[image: Sidebar --> Bonjour]

Uncheck Bonjour computers, wait a few seconds, and re-check it. That should clear out the shared computer.

Comment: This simply prevents Bonjour computers from showing in the sidebar in Finder—this neither disables Bonjour or refreshes Bonjour?

Comment: Yes that is correct checking or unchecking Bonjour does nothing and I have never had Bonjour checked.

Comment: Just a thought. I've seen this happen before and doing what I described worked.

Answer (score 0):

Devices shown in Network are reported by the network, not by your machine, hence they can't be deleted. Try restarting your router to clear any persistent assignments.

Comment: Restarting the router makes no difference.